# Multivariable optimization- Nature of critical points when det of hessian matrix = 0

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I'm struggling a bit with my multivariable optimization. Assuming the determinant of the hessian matrix ≠ 0 I have no issue, though when the det = 0 I get stumped.
Example-
$$f(x,y)=x^4+y^4-(x+y)^2$$

The Hessian comes to:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        12x^2-2 & -2 \\
        -2 & 12y^2-2 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
The critical points come to 
(1,1,-2) -Local Minima,
(-1,-1,-2) - Local Minima,
(0,0,0) - ?$$-$$
The det for (0,0,0) comes to 0 in the Hessian and as a result is a negative semi definite so could be a saddle point, max or neither. Beyond that I don't know what to do.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) On the line $y=-x$, $\;\;f(x,-x)=2x^4>0=f(0,0)$ for $x\ne0$,

$\hspace{.3 in}$so $f(0,0)$ is not a local maximum.

2) On the line $y=0$, $\;\;f(x,0)=x^4-x^2=x^2(x^2-1)<0=f(0,0)$ for $0<x<1$,

$\hspace{.3 in}$so $f(0,0)$ is not a local minimum.

Therefore $f$ has a saddle point at $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, could you explain the intuition behind how you answer this? I'm still not fully clear as to why we've set y=-x or y=0 Is the same method/approach used everytime when faced with this sort of situation.

Comment: I was trying to find 2 lines (or other curves) through the critical point which ruled out having a maximum and a minimum; usually I start with the x- and y-axes (assuming the point is the origin), and then look at other lines if necessary.  In this case, I used $y=-x$ since it made the second term vanish.